# TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am using this version of solidity, `pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;`

Whenever I compile truffle I get this `TypeError: Member "length"`. When I change the version to `0.4.0` the error goes away, but  I can't use this version. I need to use this `pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;`

Here is the error:

```
     TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.
  --> project:/contracts/Ballot1.sol:23:9:
   |
23 |         proposals.length = _numProposal;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
```

Comment: why don't you use `slice` to reduce your array instead of changing the length property ? `proposal = proposal.slice(0, _numProposal);`. If `proposal` is declared as const and thus not reassignable use another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

From Solidity v0.6.0 and onwards, you can use an array slice such as `proposals[start:end]` (note: [it only supports calldata array](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/types.html#arrays)).

Otherwise, I think you might need to build a copy of the array like so:

```
function slice(
  uint256 start,
  uint256 end,
  uint256[] memory proposals
) public pure returns (uint256[] memory) {
  uint256[] memory result;

  uint256 idx = 0;

  for (uint256 i = start; i < end; i++) {
      result[idx] = proposals[i];
      idx++;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note this operation can be quite costly if you have a large array.